# VS11- How to open the sample application downloaded from Extention Manager

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In Visual studio 11 Developer Preview, you can download samples from the extension manager, but is there an easy way to open those samples.

I know the files are downloaded to

> C:\Users****\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Extensions

, but it's probably not an good idea to open the project from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the [answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditor/thread/fc71a669-6b98-471d-9101-d5eee070c43d/#fc71a669-6b98-471d-9101-d5eee070c43d) on MSDN forum.

> After having installed the sample, you can go into the New Project
>   dialog. You will notice there is a Samples node available now, and the
>   sample you just installed should be listed in the categories there.
>   Pick the sample, and create a new project based on the sample.
>
> Also, there is a more streamlined way to do this. If you start in the
>   New Project dialog, click on the Online tab... This will query the
>   MSDN Samples Gallery and show you the same online samples in that
>   dialog. From there you can find the sample you want, install it, and
>   create a new project based on that sample in one easy step.